# Phone number recognition in sms body in android

Tags: android, sms, phone-number

I want to study how android works when sms sends. More precisely - I want to know how android recognizes phone number in sms body, like in the next photos:

For example, somebody sent me sms with the next text: **You can use the next phone number: 0673452345**
[image]

2) Then I opened this sms
[image]

3) And after this, I clicked on the recognized phone number

[image]

So I want to know what class or couple of classes does (do) this recognition. May be someone knows where I can find this in android sources.

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

This is it  [click here](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) this site has all things you want to know about sms please have a look at it. It contains sending and receiving  of sms and all about it...

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is done within the application. Any sequence of successive digits (maybe within some bounds, at least x at most y digits) is interpreted as a phone number.

Comment: I agree with you, but maybe you know what class does this, because I need Android sources..

Answer (score 0):

For This you can simply check for any 5 or more successive digits in string.
If found then replace number by something like this. number and at time of show parse that and make a link for that.